# Ignite with Cassandra integration

Tags: c++, cassandra, ignite

I am trying to integrate Ignite with Cassandra. I am using persistence strategy as BLOB. when i run the program it shows an error like "com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.CodecNotFoundException: Codec not found for requested operation: [varchar <-> java.nio.HeapByteBuffer]  at com.datastax.driver.core.CodecRegistry.notFound(CodecRegistry.java:679)
"

here is my persistence xml file

```
<persistence keyspace="sam" table="key">
<keyPersistence class="java.lang.String" strategy="BLOB" column="key"/>
<valuePersistence class="java.lang.String" strategy="BLOB" column="value"/>
</persistence>
```

main.cpp

```
int main()
{
IgniteConfiguration cfg;
cfg.springCfgPath = "apache-ignite-fabric-2.0.0-bin/cassandra-config.xml";
Ignite grid = Ignition::Start(cfg);
Cache<Test, Test> cache = grid.GetCache<Test, Test>("cache1");
Test obj;
cache.LoadCache ();
Test key;
key.key = "123dfsdfs";
obj.value = "sdfsf";
cache.Put (key,obj);
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The error means that the type of the column in Cassandra is `varchar`, but you're trying to write a BLOB into it. Thus the failure.

But why do you use `BLOB` strategy for strings? You can write a string as is to a `varchar` column by using `PRIMITIVE` strategy instead.

Comment: When i changed the strategy it works fine for strings :) . But Actually i want to use a class instead "java.lang.String". so i just changed keyPersistence class="com.test.Test". it shows other error like "Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to serialize object of the class 'com.test.Test'   Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: com.test.Test"

Comment: I believe that's because `Test` is not `Serializable` :)

Comment: Is it possible to achieve the same result if i am changing the strategy to POJO. (if i am using POJO then i can avoid the serialization right?)

Comment: Yes, with POJO strategy individual fields will be persisted in different columns. But you will have to create full schema in Cassandra for this.

Comment: I have tried this using POJO but when i put the data to cassandra only key is inserted to the table all other value columns shows NULL. i am using the same code and persistence.xml file changed to     <persistence keyspace="sam" table="key">
 <keyPersistence class="com.test.Test" strategy="POJO">
  <partitionKey>
   <field name="assetid" column="assetid" />
  </partitionKey>
 </keyPersistence>
 <valuePersistence class="com.test.Test" strategy="POJO">
  <field name="asset_desc" column="asset_desc"/>
 </valuePersistence>
</persistence>

Comment: Is `asset_desc` correct name of the field in your Java class?

Comment: Can you create a small project on GitHub that reproduces the issue?

Comment: Ok. I will do that. But i think its take some time. my config file and code details are already posted in another question. Please take a look at this. After the project creation i will share the link to you.                                          https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44178514/ignite-c-client-for-cassandra-integration?rq=1

Comment: Here is the link for Github. code add in include path of a other project. sorry for the inconvenience  https://github.com/ShijinXincoz/cctz/tree/master/include